# Sinking charge from LED before taking measurement

Tags: stm32, adc

I'm currently using an STM32 for anode sensing of a LED as shown in the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwUBqw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED is both used for emitting and for measuring light. When emitting light both MOSFETs are switched on and when sensing light they are switched off and the voltage at the LED's gate is measured using an analog input. In anode sensing this voltage is proportional to the received light. The emit-sense-cycle should be performed several hundred times per second.

The issue that I'm facing is the capacitance of the LED. As soon as both MOSFETs are turned off the anode is floating free. As such the voltage at the anode drops immediately to the diode's forward voltage, but then the LED's internal capacitance discharges slowly over several milliseconds, severely hampering my ADC measurements and preventing any faster cycles.

The issue could be solved by sinking the charge at the anode to ground before taking the measurement, though. The question is what's the best way to achieve this ? I could reconfigure the GPIO pin from analog in to digital and sink the charge using a LOW signal, but is there a more elegant way to do this, i.e. by activating some pull-down resistor at the analog in on-the-fly ?

Comment: How is the circuit going to work if M2 is turned off? Where does the led current flow?
Also, the choice of mosfets for a 3V3 system is not good.

Comment: Usually the LED is inverted (anode to ground) to work as a photodiode. See https://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/how-to-use-leds-to-detect-light/. I agree with Kartman that disconnecting the cathode will just leave the ADC input floating.

Comment: That read out circuit for the LED doesn't work for a few reasons.  First, M2 does nothing since it  has to be on for both receive and transmit.  Second, your photodiode is a current source, so when M1 is off, photocurrent generated by the LED must flow through the ADC (very high impedance) or M1 (very high impedance). You want to switch between a circuit where the voltage drives current through the LED (RX) and one where the ADC measures voltage created by photocurrent moving through a resistor (TX).

Comment: @Kartman - sorry for the confusion. Those MOSFETs are just to illustrate the principle. I use a different switch, so the actual type of MOSFET doesn't matter.

Comment: @Transistor - a floating LED under light builds up some charge which is what I want to measure. But as pointed out in my posting when I start my measurement there's still plenty of charge left in the LED from lighting it. If I wait for a couple of milliseconds that charge drops and the light-induced charge takes over, but the problem is that I want to speed things up and as such I have to find a way to change the STM analog input to a digital output and discharge through that pin by setting it to low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I solved it by switching the GPIO port between analog in for reading and digital out with an internal pull-down for discharging the capacitance.

In order to perform the switch I manipulated the STM32F303RET6's MODER and PUPDR registers directly, which is very fast.

Very pleased with the solution.

```
// configure DMA and ADC
...
// save existing register values for undoing the change once the capacitance is discharged
_moderA = GPIOA->MODER;
_pupdrA = GPIOA->PUPDR;
_moderC = GPIOC->MODER;
_pupdrC = GPIOC->PUPDR;
/**
 * Pinout
 *
 * A0   PA4
 * A1   PA5
 * A2   PA6
 * A3   PA7
 * A4   PC4
 * A5   PC5
 * A6   PC0
 * A7   PC1
 * A8   PC2
 * A9   PC3
 */
// switch to digital out and enable internal pull-down resistors on the fly
GPIOA->MODER &= 0b11111111111111110101010111111111;  // set PA4-PA7 to general output
GPIOC->MODER &= 0b11111111111111111111010101010101;  // set PC0-PC5 to general output
GPIOA->PUPDR &= 0b11111111111111111010101011111111;  // set PA4-PA7 to use pull-down
GPIOC->MODER &= 0b11111111111111111111101010101010;  // set PC0-PC5 to use pull-down

// switch back to analog in
GPIOA->PUPDR = _pupdrA;
GPIOA->MODER = _moderA;
GPIOC->PUPDR = _pupdrC;
GPIOC->MODER = _moderC;

// take measurement using ADC
...
```